# How to share files between containers in the same kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have two containers, one running phpfpm and the other running nginx. I'd like the container running nginx to access the webroot files which has css and javascript files. Right now, nginx successfully passes off php requests to phpfpm, but no styles are showing up for instance when the webpage is rendered.

This is running off of minikube on a linux system.

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: php-ini
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
data:
  php.ini: |
    extension=intl.so
    extension=pdo_mysql.so
    extension=sodium
    extension=zip.so
    zend_extension=opcache.so

    [php]
    session.auto_start = Off
    short_open_tag = Off
    opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
    opcache.max_accelerated_files = 20000
    opcache.memory_consumption = 256
    realpath_cache_size = 4096K
    realpath_cache_ttl = 600
    expose_php = off
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-conf
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
data:
  default.conf: |-
    server {
        listen 80;

        root /srv/app/webroot/;
        index index.php;

        location / {
          try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-nginx-deployment
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
  labels:
    app: php-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: php
          image: mixerapidev/demo:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: php-secret
                  key: database-url
            - name: SECURITY_SALT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: php-secret
                  key: cakephp-salt
          volumeMounts:
            - name: php-ini
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
            - name: php-application
              mountPath: /application

        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:1.19-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-conf
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
            - name: php-application
              mountPath: /application

      volumes:
        - name: php-ini
          configMap:
            name: php-ini
        - name: php-application
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: php-application-pv-claim
        - name: nginx-conf
          configMap:
            name: nginx-conf
            items:
              - key: default.conf
                path: default.conf
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: php-application-pv-claim
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
  labels:
    app: php-nginx
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
spec:
  selector:
    app: php-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30002
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
spec:
  selector:
    app: php-nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
```

Comment: if it is serving content but not styles (are you getting a 404 or something else?) then it sounds more like an nginx configuration problem.  Can you confirm if your stylesheet is resulting in a 404 or some other status code?  And can you post your nginx config file?  NM about the config file... I see it in your configmap

Comment: Eh, I figured it out by reading this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993636/how-to-share-files-between-containers-in-the-same-kubernetes-pod I'm not sure if its better to just run php/nginx in a single container or going with what that person posted. I'll update my post with an answer...

Comment: Hi @cnizzardini, it seems like you've provided the answer in the question. Could you please provide it in the answer under this question? Mainly to indicate that this question was resolved and to give more visibility to future readers. Also does the link that's you've included are correct (they are referencing to this exact post)?

Comment: @DawidKruk sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but I based it off of this:
[How to share files between containers in the same kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67993636/how-to-share-files-between-containers-in-the-same-kubernetes-pod)

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: php-ini
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
data:
  php.ini: |
    extension=intl.so
    extension=pdo_mysql.so
    extension=sodium
    extension=zip.so
    zend_extension=opcache.so

    [php]
    session.auto_start = Off
    short_open_tag = Off
    opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
    opcache.max_accelerated_files = 20000
    opcache.memory_consumption = 256
    realpath_cache_size = 4096K
    realpath_cache_ttl = 600
    expose_php = off
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-conf
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
data:
  default.conf: |-
    server {
        listen 80;

        root /application/webroot/;
        index index.php;

        location / {
          try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-nginx-deployment
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
  labels:
    app: php-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: php
          image: mixerapidev/demo:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: php-secret
                  key: database-url
            - name: SECURITY_SALT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: php-secret
                  key: cakephp-salt
          volumeMounts:
            - name: php-ini
              mountPath: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
            - name: application
              mountPath: /application
          lifecycle:
            postStart:
              exec:
                command:
                  - "/bin/sh"
                  - "-c"
                  - >
                    cp -r /srv/app/. /application/.

        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:1.19-alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: nginx-conf
              mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
            - name: application
              mountPath: /application

      volumes:
        - name: php-ini
          configMap:
            name: php-ini
        - name: nginx-conf
          configMap:
            name: nginx-conf
            items:
              - key: default.conf
                path: default.conf
        - name: application
          emptyDir: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
spec:
  selector:
    app: php-nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30002
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php
  namespace: mixerapi-docker
spec:
  selector:
    app: php-nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
```

I had composer install running in a docker entrypoint, so I needed to move that into the Dockerfile for this to work. I updated my Dockerfile with this and removed install from my entrypoint if the ENV is prod:

```
RUN if [[ "$ENV" = "prod" ]]; then \
    composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction --no-dev; \
fi
```